# For flutter projects, should I check-in runner.entitlements file into version control?

Tags: flutter

This seems to be an auto-generated file by flutter for iOS. I can see it being referred in
the file, *Runner/project.pbxproj*
`CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = Runner/Runner.entitlements;`

I could also see it not listed in the [flutter/.gitignore](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/.gitignore)